# How to use ZigZag Lib in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Tradingviews documentation didn't bring me further. I am struggling to use the ZigZag Library. I have found a even [better library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/lRY74dha-Absolute-ZigZag-Lib/), I would like to apply.

How do I access the last and previous last high and low values?

This is what I tried yet:

```
import niquedegraaff/Absolute_ZigZag_Lib/10 as pivotLib
latestHigh = pivotLib.getLastHigh(pivotLib)
prevHigh = pivotLib.getHigh(pivotLib, 2)

latestLow = pivotLib.getLastLow(pivotLib)
prevLow = pivotLib.getLow(pivotLib, 2)
```

instead of pivotLib for 'this' I also tried 'close' and 'pivotLib.Pivot' etc.

Comment: Alternativly I could use the TV ZigZagLib but this is even less documented. There are no example. Would be really happy about some help

Answer (score 0):

if your latest high is in `latestHigh`,
you can access the previous high with :

```
prevHigh = latestHigh[1]
```

Comment: The problem is pivotLab. Since the argument for the get_methods isn't accepted. This is the error I get with 1: "Cannot call 'pivotLib.getLastLow' with argument 'this'='1'. An argument of 'literal int' type was used but a 'Pivot[] type from niquedegraaff/Absolute_ZigZag_Lib/10' is expected."